# Symfony2: Unable to access the web directory from the entity class

Tags: php, symfony, path, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use the cookbook example on how to upload fiels with symfony2 :
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

The problem is that I am not able to get the path of the web folder.

Here are some details: In my web folder, I have a structure like that:

```
/web
    /bundles
        /sciforumversion2
            /images
```

And from the entity, I I trying to get the folder path and save my image in the /images folder

For that, I am using:

```
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'sciforumversion2/bundles/images';
}
```

But I am getting then the exception that the directory can't be created:

```
Unable to create the "/home/milos/workspace/conference2.0/src/SciForum/Version2Bundle/Entity/../../../../web/sciforumversion2/bundles/images/conference" directory
```

Any idea on how could I get the web folder url and why the solution proposed by the symfony cookbook is not working is mostly welcome.

Thank you very much.
Thank you.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle would be something nice for you

Comment: Thank you, but I have everythink working in my personal bundle, except the dir problem, so I prefer to use what I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path seems to be correct.

Probably you should give it the correct permissions.

Try this first:

```
chmod 777 /home/milos/workspace/conference2.0/src/SciForum/Version2Bundle/Entity/../../../../web/sciforumversion2/bundles/images/
```

If that works, it's a permission issue.
Set the owner and group to www-data using:

```
chown www-data:www-data /home/milos/workspace/conference2.0/src/SciForum/Version2Bundle/Entity/../../../../web/sciforumversion2/bundles/images/
chmod 755 /home/milos/workspace/conference2.0/src/SciForum/Version2Bundle/Entity/../../../../web/sciforumversion2/bundles/images/
```

Comment: That is, it works now, thanks a lot. A +1 from me and I have confirmed your answer.